# Put the Memory Usage in a TProgressBar.position with Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, memory, vcl

I would like to know how do I take the Memory Usage of the computer being used and put the amount in a `TProgressBar` component.

I know it is possible to take the CPU Usage and put it there, but I don't know how to do it with the Memory. How do I do this?

Comment: First of all you need to define memory usage and then cpu usage. A good start might be the Process Hacker source.

Comment: This question can helps you...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779234/delphi-2007-globalmemorystatus-to-get-total-ram

Answer (score 2):

I think I have got what you need.

```
unit RamMonitor;

interface

uses
  Classes, Windows, SyncObjs;

type
  TOnRefresh = Procedure(RAMUsage: Double) of object;
  TOnRefreshExt = Procedure(RAMUsage: Double; RAMTotal, RAMFree, RAMUsed: Integer) of object;

type
  TRAMMonitor = class(TThread)
    private
      FPauseEvent : TEvent;
      FOnRefresh: TOnRefresh;
      FOnRefreshExt: TOnRefreshExt;

      FRefreshInterval: Integer;
      FRAMUsage: Double;
      FRAMTotal: Integer;
      FRAMFree: Integer;
      FRAMUsed: Integer;

      procedure ReportRAMUsage;
      procedure CheckForPause;
    public
      property RefreshInterval : Integer read FRefreshInterval write FRefreshInterval;
      property OnRefresh: TOnRefresh read FOnRefresh write FOnRefresh;
      property OnRefreshExt: TOnRefreshExt read FOnRefreshExt write FOnRefreshExt;

      constructor Create; reintroduce;
      destructor Destroy; override;
      procedure Pause;
      procedure UnPause;
    protected
      procedure Execute; override;
  end;

const
  ONEMEGABYTE   = 1024 * 1024;
  INTERVAL      = 5000; //ms

implementation

constructor TRAMMonitor.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(true);

  FPauseEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, true, true, '');
  FRefreshInterval := INTERVAL;
end;

destructor TRAMMonitor.Destroy;
begin
  if not Terminated then
    Terminate;
  FPauseEvent.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TRAMMonitor.CheckForPause;
begin
  FPauseEvent.WaitFor(INFINITE);
end;

procedure TRAMMonitor.Pause;
begin
  FPauseEvent.ResetEvent;
end;

procedure TRAMMonitor.UnPause;
begin
  FPauseEvent.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TRAMMonitor.Execute;
var
  x, y : real;
  memory: Windows.TMemoryStatus;
begin
  repeat
    CheckForPause;
    // memory
    memory.dwLength := SizeOf(memory);
    GlobalMemoryStatus(memory);
    x := memory.dwTotalPhys - memory.dwAvailPhys;
    y := memory.dwTotalPhys;
    FRAMUsage := ((x/y)*100);
    FRAMTotal := round(memory.dwTotalPhys/ONEMEGABYTE);
    FRAMFree := round(memory.dwAvailPhys/ONEMEGABYTE);
    FRAMUsed := round((memory.dwTotalPhys - memory.dwAvailPhys)/ONEMEGABYTE);

    Synchronize(ReportRAMUsage);
    sleep(FRefreshInterval);
  until (Terminated);
end;

procedure TRAMMonitor.ReportRAMUsage;
begin
  if Assigned(OnRefresh) then
    OnRefresh(FRAMUsage);

  if Assigned(OnRefreshExt) then
    OnRefreshExt(FRAMUsage, FRAMTotal, FRAMFree, FRAMUsed);
end;

end.
```

in the init code of your main :

```
FRAMUsage := TRamMonitor.Create;
FRAMUsage.RefreshInterval := 15000; // 15s
FRAMUsage.OnRefresh := RefreshRamUsage;
FRAMUsage.Unpause; // in order to make the thread run
```

and here is the refreshing proc, in this example the usage is in percent so ou need to set the max to 100.
the second event (which is not used in this example) gives more detail about the memory usage in megabytes.

```
procedure TfrmMain.RefreshRamUsage(Usage: Double);
var
  NewPos : Integer;
begin
  NewPos := Trunc(Usage);
  pbRamUsage.Position := NewPos;
end;
```

hth

Comment: Isn't there a simpler method?

Comment: I'm looking for a quick and easy way.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at this question from 2015 and now I like your answer. Thank you. I will test it out sometime this week.